# script only works when alert() is unescaped?

Tags: javascript

I got a script which works in IE and chrome but not in FF.. Or it works in all three if I unescape the line where 'x' is alerted!?

in FF 3.6 the div is first visible when the script is half done.. it just jumps to the middle of the "moving line"

```
<div id="tst" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px; height:100px; width:100px; background:#ff0000"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Tween(){
        this.time = 0;
        this.duration = 800;
        this.x_start = 0;
        this.x_end = 0;

        this.target_func = null;

        this.method_func = null;
        this.loop = null;
        this.interval = 20;

        this.start = function(){
            if(!this.method_func){
                this.method_func = this.regularEaseOut;
            }

            var _this = this;
            this.loop = setInterval(function(){
                if(_this.set_time() > 0){
                    var x = _this.method_func();
                    //alert(x);
                    _this.target_func(x);
                }
            }, this.interval);
        };

        this.set_time = function(){
            this.time += this.interval;
            if(this.time > this.duration){
                clearInterval(this.loop);
                this.time = 0;
            }

            return this.time;
        };

        this.regularEaseInOut = function(){
            var t = this.time;
            var s = this.x_start;
            var e = this.x_end;
            var d = this.duration;

            if((t/=d/2) < 1){
                return c/2*t*t + b;
            }
            else{
                return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
            }
        };

        this.regularEaseIn = function(){
            var t = this.time;
            var s = this.x_start;
            var e = this.x_end;
            var d = this.duration;

            return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
        };

        this.regularEaseOut = function(){
            var t = this.time;
            var s = this.x_start;
            var e = this.x_end;
            var d = this.duration;

            return -e *(t/=d)*(t-2) + s;
        };
    }

    var Tween = new Tween();
    Tween.x_start = 200;
    Tween.x_end = 1200;
    Tween.target_func = function(x){
        document.getElementById('tst').style.left = x+'px';
    };
    Tween.start();
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when it “doesn't work”? Is there an error? Or strange behaviour? Or just nothing?

Comment: the div is only visible when the script is half done.. it just jumps to the middle of the "moving line"

Comment: Check in the Error Console for any Javascript errors

Comment: By "unescaped", do you mean "uncommented"?

Comment: Works in FF4 for me. It's just a bit jerky.

Comment: Any reason you're using `(t/=d)` in the middle of your expression? That's probably bad practice.

Comment: Describing what you expect the script to do and what happens instead in FF would help a lot.

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem? If so, an upvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function Tween(){
          this.time = 0;
          this.duration = 800;
          this.x_start = 0;
          this.x_end = 0;

          this.target_func = null;

          this.method_func = null;
          this.loop = null;
          this.interval = 20;

          this.start = function(){
              if(!this.method_func){
                  this.method_func = this.regularEaseOut;
              }

              var _this = this;
              this.loop = setInterval(function(){
                  if(_this.set_time() > 0){
                      var x = _this.method_func();
                      //alert(x);
                      _this.target_func(x);
                  }
              }, this.interval);
          };

          this.set_time = function(){
              this.time += this.interval;
              if(this.time > this.duration){
                  clearInterval(this.loop);
                  this.time = 0;
              }

              return this.time;
          };

          this.regularEaseInOut = function(){
              var t = this.time;
              var s = this.x_start;
              var e = this.x_end;
              var d = this.duration;

              if((t/=d/2) < 1){
                  return c/2*t*t + b;
              }
              else{
                  return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
              }
          };

          this.regularEaseIn = function(){
              var t = this.time;
              var s = this.x_start;
              var e = this.x_end;
              var d = this.duration;

              return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
          };

          this.regularEaseOut = function(){
              var t = this.time;
              var s = this.x_start;
              var e = this.x_end;
              var d = this.duration;

              return -e *(t/=d)*(t-2) + s;
          };
      }

      function doYourThing() {
        var tween = new Tween();
        tween.x_start = 200;
        tween.x_end = 1200;
        tween.target_func = function(x){
            document.getElementById('tst').style.left = x+'px';
        };
        tween.start();
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="doYourThing()">
  <div id="tst" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px; height:100px; width:100px; background:#ff0000"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So using onload makes sure the method is only run once the document is loaded. Also, you made an instance variable (Tween) with the same name as the "class" you want to instantiate. That will definitely cause you pain and misery down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The `alert` stops the execution of the code until `Ok` is pressed. Check if this can be the source of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean not works?

if you mean it's not moving to the right, It works for me in my FF 4.0.1